# int ** array changing value

Tags: c, pointer-to-pointer

So I have an `int **`. It contains pixel values. What I'm trying to do is change the value of a set number of pixel values; say the value is 90, I want to change it to the max level that it has to create a black edge of x amount of pixels. I've been messing around with it for the last hour and can't seem to figure out how to change the actual value inside the **

This is what I have so far:

```
int pgmDrawEdge( int **pixels, int numRows, int numCols, int edgeWidth, char **header ){
    int i=0, j=0, count=0;

    int intensity=atoi(header[2]);

    while(count<edgeWidth){
        for(; i<numRows; i++){
            for(; j<numCols; j++){
                pixels[i][j]=intensity;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the main function call:
`pgmDrawCircle(pixel, rows, cols, circleCenterRow, circleCenterCol, radius, header);`

I think I have the right idea, but like I mentioned above I just can't seem to figure out how to get the value to change.

I don't think I do, but do I need to allocate memory? It's being passed in from the main so I don't think I would need to since it is already full...correct?

As per request here is pgmRead:

```
int ** pgmRead( char **header, int *numRows, int *numCols, FILE *in  ){
    int i, j, temp, intensity;

    fgets(header[0], maxSizeHeadRow, in);
    fgets(header[1], maxSizeHeadRow, in);

    fscanf(in, "%d %d", numCols, numRows);
    fscanf(in, "%d", &intensity);
    sprintf(header[2], "%d", intensity);

    int **ptr=(int **)malloc(*numRows*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i<*numRows; i++){
        ptr[i]=(int *)malloc(*numCols*sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i=0; i<*numRows; i++){
        for(j=0; j<*numCols; j++){
            fscanf(in, "%d", &temp);
            ptr[i][j]=temp; 
        }
    }

    fclose(in);
    return ptr;
}
```

In the main function:

```
    int **pixel=NULL;
    pixel=pgmRead(header, &rows, &cols, in);

if(strcmp(argv[1],"-e")==0){
    printf("Edge Drawing\n");
    pgmDrawEdge(pixel, rows, cols, edgeWidth, header);
}
```

Comment: post your main, when you call the function

Comment: Is pixel allocated dynamically through malloc?

Comment: I have another function that returns an int** to the main function. When I send it to another function I can still access everything and print out the contents of pixels

Comment: Can we see the function that allocates & fills the `int **`?

Comment: You aren't telling pgmDrawEdge the shape of your pixels array.

Comment: @Kninnug Function has been added

Comment: Show us where pgmDrawEdge() is being called.

Comment: I have another function that will write the contents of the 2d array to a file. It works just fine and I am calling it the same way. I still get a picture to print out. It's only when I'm trying to change the value of the array that I don't get anything to happen

Comment: I asked for the `pgmDrawEdge()` function. Anyways, check the ans I posted, that is one of the errors in your code.

Comment: @brokenfoot pgmDrawEdge is already at the top of the question

Comment: `for(; i<numRows; i++){
            for(; j<numCols; j++){` your inner loop is only performs one scan. And so is your outer loop... which means that the `while(count<edgeWidth){` increments count, which is never used.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you paste the code for `pgmDrawEdge()`, yet you call `pgmDrawCircle()` from main, could that be the problem in the first place?

Comment: @sgorozco oops I posted the wrong piece of code ha

Comment: @sgorozco fixed it, the correct piece of code is in there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your pgmDrawEdge pretty much works as this test shows.  So problem is elsewhere

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int pgmDrawEdge( int **pixels, int numRows, int numCols, int edgeWidth, char **header ){
    int i=0, j=0, count=0;

    int intensity=atoi(header[2]);

    while(count<edgeWidth){
        for(; i<numRows; i++){
            for(; j<numCols; j++){
                pixels[i][j]=intensity;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
 char *header[]={"abc","def","90"};
 int *x[2];
 int l1[]={1,2,3,4};
 int l2[]={5,6,7,8};
 x[0]=l1;
 x[1]=l2;
pgmDrawEdge(x,2,4,99,header);
printf("result is %d should be %s", x[0][0], header[2] );
    return(0) ;
}
```